# phonegap image upload redirect when finished

Tags: file, redirect, upload

I have the following code for Phonegap to upload a image to PHP , which works , but when it is finished I want to redirect to index.html, although control never seems to return to where the ft.upload() is executed - what do I need to do to redirect when the upload is finished??

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#post_id").val("8");
    var ls_token    = get_token("token");
    alert( ls_token );
    $("#token_id").val( ls_token );     
    //
    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,
                                    function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
                                    { 
                                            quality: 50, 
                                            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                                            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY                                         }
        );
    }

    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        //options.fileKey="img";
        options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";
        options.params = params;
        //options.chunkedMode = false;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, "http://example.com/add_pictures/", win, fail, options );
        // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
        window.location.replace("index.html");      // <-- not executed..

    }
    function win(r) {
        alert("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        alert("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
        window.location.replace("index.html");      // <-- not executed..
    }

    function fail(error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        alert("upload error source " + error.source);
        alert("upload error target " + error.target);
    }

}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to sort this myself...eventually. I created a new project using "phonegap create.." - also updated the cordova version. 
In the config.xml I added this:

```
<edit-config target="NSCameraUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need camera access to take pictures</string>
</edit-config>

<edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need photo library access to get pictures from there</string>
</edit-config>

<edit-config target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need location access to find things nearby</string>
</edit-config>

<edit-config target="NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">
    <string>need photo library access to save pictures there</string>
</edit-config>
```

And in manifest.xml I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Also according to this article:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/
file transfer is deprecated, after a bit of research people seem to be using: 
XMLHttpRequest, so I changed the transfer code to :

```
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("file", file);
        fd.append("id","88");
 var posts = new XMLHttpRequest();
posts.onreadystatechange = function() { // listen for state changes
  if (posts.readyState == 4 && posts.status == 200) { // when completed we can move away
    window.location = "done.html";
  }
}
posts.open("POST",  'http://example.com/test1.php',   true);
posts.send(fd);
```

Not sure which of these actually solved the problem. I am guessing as I was trying things in the original project something was changed or added that upset it